# Не работает реализация интерфейса

Tags: c#, winforms, интерфейс

Приветствую. В приложении WinForms есть 2 режима работы - админ и юзер в зависимости от логина и пароля которые он ввел. режимы отличаются количеством отображаемых элементов(кнопочек, лаиблов и тд).  что бы на каждой форме не писать во время загрузки перечень того что видит а что не видит юзер решил организовать процесс через 1 класс поведения, интерфейс и несколько классов реализаторов. Но нужные элементы не скрываются, в этом проблема. Собственно код :

```
interface Idostup
{
    void setFunctions();
}
```

главный класс, через обьект которого происходит реализация интерфейса :

```
class dostupModul
{
    public Idostup functionsCommand { get; set; }

    public void setControll()
    {
        functionsCommand.setFunctions();

    }
}
```

для примера один из классов, реализующих разное поведение :

```
class mainFormFunction : Idostup
{
    public void setFunctions()
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.lbl_levelDostup.Visible = false;  // это не работает
        MessageBox.Show("ewwerwerwer",""); // это работает

      }
}
```

И загрузка самой формы на которой нужно что то скрыть :

```
    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dostupModul M = new dostupModul();
        M.functionsCommand = new mainFormFunction();
        M.setControll();
```

Что не так написал, где ошибся подскажите ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаёте новый объект `Main` в методе `setFunctions`, устанавливаете ему какое-то свойство и всё, дальше ничего с этим объектом не происходит. Делаете вы это в методе `Main_Load`, который принадлежит ***другому объекту*** `Main`. Вам нужно передавать объект `Main`, событие загрузки которого срабатывает, в метод `setFunctions`.

Например:

```
interface Idostup
{
    void setFunctions(Main main);
}
class dostupModul
{
    private Main _main;

    public dostupModul(Main main)
    {
        _main = main;
    }

    public Idostup functionsCommand { get; set; }

    public void setControll()
    {
        functionsCommand.setFunctions(_main);    
    }
}
class mainFormFunction : Idostup
{
    public void setFunctions(Main main)
    {
        main.lbl_levelDostup.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("ewwerwerwer","");    
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dostupModul M = new dostupModul(this);
    M.functionsCommand = new mainFormFunction();
    M.setControll();
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59775/discussion-on-answer-by-dm-dymov----).